# Als sonstiges möchte ich Computer schreiben

Tags: translation

I would need help with the sentence I posted in the title since my language (and the Wörterbuch I have) leaves gaps for several interpretations. I will enclose the text the sentence is part of. It is an extract of a longer conversation. This is the man's dialogue. Almost at the very end of the conversation.

> Eh, du ich schmeisse dich bald ins Wasser!! Na, was mich wohl interessiert? Naja, praktisch alles. Aber bestimmt Musik, Kino und Federball spielen. *Als sonstiges möchte ich Computer schreiben*

What does: "Als sonstiges möchte ich Computer schreiben" mean?

Comment: Where did you find this German text? It doesn't sound like a bad translation and not like a original German text.

Comment: Note that the nominalization _[Sonstiges](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sonstig)_ is written with a capital letter: _Über Sonstiges wurde nicht gesprochen. Das Sonstige erledigen wir morgen._

Comment: Written with small first letter in my textbuch.

Comment: Sounds to me like bad German like it is written in facebook or similar sozial media sites. The last sentence is faulty. As it stands here it makes no sense, and there are many different ways how it could be corrected to a meaningful sentence, but we all do not know which correction would meet the actors intention. So either ask the author what he/she wanted to say (if possible) or just forget this crab.

Comment: Die Quelle: Titel, Verlag, Autor, Jahr, Seitenzahl bitte. Und gibt es in dem Text Auszeichnungen, also Kursiv- oder Fettdruck?

Comment: If this is from the same text book you are referring to in other posts, I'd say it would be better to get another textbook from another author, to learn more ideomatic German

Comment: You should specify, what different interpretations you came up with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In forms or questionnaires you can enter your hobbys or interests. Sometimes, there are rather checkboxes (*I'm interested in: [X] travels [X] cinema [X] football*...), and if no answer is correct, the last checkbox says **Sonstiges** (*something different*).

The text you pasted looks like a description of how somebody would fill such a questionnaire and what he/she would enter in the last field *Sonstiges*. With correct interpunction, it would be:

> Als "Sonstiges" möchte ich "Computer" schreiben.

Comment: Korrekte Interpunktion ist Anführungsstriche für direkte Rede und Zitate. Als Fortbewegungsmittel will ich Räder nutzen. Als Brotaufstrich will ich Nuss-Nougat-Creme essen.

Comment: @userunknown Da bin ich nicht einverstanden. "Computer" ist in diesem Fall ein Zitat - denn es beschreibt, was jemand *schreiben* würde. Im Gegensatz dazu: *Als Werkzeug will ich Computer nutzen* - ohne Anführungsstriche. Einen Computer kann man nicht schreiben. Aber man "Computer" schreiben. Und das "Sonstiges" steht ebenso völlig korrekt in Anführungsstrichen, denn es gibt an, was irgendwo *geschrieben steht*. Der Umfragenautor hätte den letzten Punkt auch anders formulieren können: *Als "Sonstige Interessen" möchte ich dies und jenes schreiben*

Comment: Ein Zitat von wem? Einzelne Wörter sind kein Zitat. Es hat auch niemand behauptet, jemand wolle einen Computer schreiben, was durchaus möglich ist, nämlich als Simulation als Computerprogramm. Ich möchte Heureka rufen. Sondern jemand wolle Computer schreiben in das Feld für Sonstiges.

Comment: Also wollte jemand eine Computersimulation in das Feld für Sonstiges schreiben? *Ich möchte eine Banane essen und Computer schreiben* - *Ich möchte einen Brief und Computer schreiben* - widerstrebt es dir nicht? Natürlich können Zitate aus einzelnen Wörtern bestehen und ein Zitat ist alles, was nur als Wortlaut aufgeführt wird. In deinem *in das Feld für Sonstiges* fehlen die Anführungsstriche korrekterweise, doch so, wie der Satz ursprünglich formuliert ist, müssen sie da sein: *Als Antwort möchte ich meine Hobbys angeben, und als "Sonstiges" möchte ich dies und jenes schreiben.*

Answer (score 0):

Hm, the text isn't realy a good translation. Perhaps you'll show the original english text? 
Only the sentence »Als sonstiges möchte ich Computer schreiben« will mean something like:

> Sonst interessiere ich mich für Computer.

Comment: I copied it as it was in German. The text is in German and i want to translate it translate it back to my language. What does is mean in English?

Comment: Eva, I don't understand the text and I'm a native.I